# Heroku run rake db:migrate?

Tags: windows, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4.2

Could you tell me what this means:

```
$ heroku run rake db:migrate
Running `rake db:migrate` attached to terminal... up, run.9927
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (10.1ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM
 "schema_migrations"
```

Is this normal output for a properly working app?

Thanks

Comment: I never used rake but I'm quite confident that a `db:migrate` is used to make your db migrations... So the message you get seems all normal.

Answer (score 0):

While deploying on heroku the "heroku run rake db:migrate" command will read your schema.rb file from app. Because when user creates new migration and run that migration, rails documents the final current state of the database schema in schema.rb file.